# Custom function not returning any output

Tags: functions, options

I'm trying to write a custom function but it isn't returning any output.

Here's my code so far:

```
Options[Alternate] = {AlternationType -> AlternationPlusMinus};

Alternate[Terms_, Exponent_, OptionsPattern[]] := (
   tmpSet = {};
   If[OptionValue[AlternationType] == AlternationPlusMinus, 
Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
  AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^Exponent) - 1] AppendTo[
    tmpSet, (counter^Exponent) + 1]], {counter, Terms}], 
Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
  AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^Exponent) + 1] AppendTo[
    tmpSet, (counter^Exponent) - 1]], {counter, Terms}]];
   Return[Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[tmpSet, x]]];
   );
Alternate[20, 2]
```

When I execute it, no output block is even generated, let alone any error messages or warnings, is there any way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: When I execute it in a fresh Mathematica kernel, I do get some output (a very large polynomial) and some error messages like  `(Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0} {0,2} cannot be combined. >>)`. Have you tried this in a fresh kernel? Also, you are not localizing `tmpSet`. Try wrapping your function with `Module`. Also, try `Fold` instead of `Do` and `Return`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris's answer (particularly the missing commas) explains why your version wasn't working. However you should also consider modularising your code so that `tmpSet` doesn't leak out to have a value elsewhere in your code:

```
Alternate[Terms_, exponent_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{tmpSet = {}},
  If[OptionValue[AlternationType] == "AlternationPlusMinus", 
   Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
     AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) - 1], 
     AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) + 1]], {counter, Terms}], 
   Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
     AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) + 1], 
     AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) - 1]], {counter, Terms}]];
  Return[Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[tmpSet, x]]]]
```

Also, the whole `Do`...`Return` paradigm is almost never the most efficient way to program in Mathematica. Here is a more functional-programming style alternative. It gives the same answers for the simple tests I have done. Notice I have restricted the definition of the function to only match for positive integer values of `terms` and `exponent`. You can of course remove them again if you intend for this function to be used for real or negative-valued inputs.

```
alternateAlternate[terms_Integer?Positive, exponent_Integer?Positive, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x]] &@
  If[OptionValue[AlternationType] == "AlternationPlusMinus", 
   FoldList[(#2^exponent) + If[OddQ[#2], -1, 1] &, 0, Range[2, terms]], 
   FoldList[(#2^exponent) + If[OddQ[#2], 1, -1] &, 2, Range[2, terms]] ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've used the second solution combined with Chris' quotes around AlternationPlusMinus. It works perfectly now! :)

Answer (score 4):

You could put `AlternationPlusMinus` in quotes.  You also have two missing commas in the `If` statements.  `Exponent` is a reserved word but doesn't prevent execution.  This version seems to work:

```
Options[Alternate] = {AlternationType -> "AlternationPlusMinus"};

Alternate[Terms_, exponent_, OptionsPattern[]] := (tmpSet = {};
   If[OptionValue[AlternationType] == "AlternationPlusMinus", 
    Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
      AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) - 1] , 
      AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) + 1]], {counter, Terms}], 
    Do[If[Mod[counter, 2] != 0, 
      AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) + 1] , 
      AppendTo[tmpSet, (counter^exponent) - 1]], {counter, Terms}]];
   Return[Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[tmpSet, x]]];);
Alternate[20, 2]
```

Comment: This still gives the `Thread::tdlen` error for me, and I do get an output. I'm currently trying to redo this function using `FoldList` but getting different answers.

Comment: @ Verbeia - I have added to my answer. Added commas.

Comment: Yes the missing commas was the issue I came up with too.